# Iterating through list which is value of a dict

Tags: python

I have many sets of JSON data, each of which looks like this after being converted into dict:

```
json_data = 
{
  "root":[
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

I want to iterate through the list `[1,2,3]` with this:

```
for value in json_data.values():
    print(value)
```

I expect to get this output:

`1`
`2`
`3`
But I get this :

`[1,2,3]`

What should I change in the code? Thanks !

Comment: `for value in json_data['root']:`

Comment: @flakes Thanks. But I won't know all the keys in this set of many JSON data. An way to use the values instead?

Comment: So you have multiple keys and know all of them are lists?

Comment: Yes, all the JSON data after being converted has one ```root``` key (which I don't know what they are), and the one value, which is a list.

Comment: You can always spread the lists: `print(*value)`. Of course, that's an error if value is not iterable.

Comment: in that case, check the type of the value: `if isinstance(value, list)` and if it is a list, iterate through it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the constraint. Adding more example with input and expected output would be more illustrative. Also point out if you want them one per line or not.

Comment: Thanks. I think @Mark's solution works well. @khuyng, using ```isinstance(value, list)``` gives me ```class(dict_value)```.

Comment: `for value in json_data.values(): for val in values: print(val)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.keys()` or `dict.values()` will give us `dict_values([[1, 2, 3]])`

So iterating through this like

```
for value in json_data.values():
    print(value)
```

will return us. Note: `json_data.values()[0]` will return an error `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

You have three options here.

**Option1** use your example but iterate twice

```
for value in json_data.values():
    for lst in value:
        print(last)
```

**Option2** if you know the key you can use `.get()` or `dict['key']`

```
for value in json_data['root']:
    print(value)
```

```
for value in json_data.get('root'):
    print(value)
```

**Option3**

```
for value in json_data.values():
    print(*value)
```

This will give you `1 2 3`
Now of course there are many more options but these are what I could think of.

Comment: You can also use `list(json_data.values())[index]`, See my answer for elaboration

Comment: I literally said "Now of course there are many more options"

Comment: Yes and I mentioned one such option, because you also said "these are what i could think of".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `dict.items()`:

```
json_data = {
    "root": [1, 2, 3]
}

for key, values in json_data.items():
  print(key, values)

  for value in values:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `list` key word so that you can use the indices of the `json_data.values()`

```
for value in list(json_data.values())[0]:
    print(value)
```

this will return: (in your example case)

```
1
2
3
```

To do this for all the keys in json_data, you can do:

```
for index in range(len(json_data.values())):
    for value in list(json_data.values())[index]:
        print(value)
```